# Convert string to valid RFC1123 DNS Subdomain

Tags: python, string, kubernetes, rfc1123

Pretty similar to [Convert any string to a valid DNS subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576943/convert-any-string-to-a-valid-dns-subdomain), except asking it for Python (I'm using 3.10) and (sort of) Kubernetes. Hoping to accomplish this in the most pythonic (i.e. just grab a library that someone else wrote) way possible.

Kubernetes [requires that resource names be a valid DNS subdomain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#dns-subdomain-names).

I'm looking for something that more or less does:

- Converts all uppercase to lowercase
- Replaces all invalid characters with something valid (e.g. `.` or `-`)
- Chops invalid characters off the end

So for example:

```
import awesomelibrary
input = 'Inv@l^d_Stuff$.-'
output = awesomelibrary.convert_to_rfc1123_compliant(input)
print(output)
```

Expected output:

```
inv-l-d-stuff
```

Comment: There are built-in functions that will accomplish the same goal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this gets it done:

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', '-', input).lower()
```